# Unable to read updated data from html to angular component

Tags: angular

I am developing an AngularApp with .netcore. In one of the angular component i am using mat step forms. I am able to display the data on the frontend with the logic i implemented. but when i want to post the data(displayed in the frontend) i am unable to display the updated value of the data.
please guide me on what i am missing.
Thanks in Advance.

app.html

```
 <mat-step>
         <h3>Data</h3>
         <form [formGroup] = "fourthFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="form4()" #formfour = "ngForm">
         <div class="row1 ">
            <div class="col-md-6">        
<form class="list" >
 <p> <input type="checkbox" name="v1" value="B" [(ngModel)]="item1.isChecked" (change)="updateTotal(item1)"> dt </p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="v2" value="C" [(ngModel)]="item2.isChecked" (change)="updateTotal(item2)"> pd</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" name="v3" value="Bt" [(ngModel)]="item3.isChecked" (change)="updateTotal(item3)"> if</p>
 total: {{total}}
</form>
</div> 
          </div>
          </form>

<!-- <mat-card>
<mat-card-content>

</mat-card-content>
</mat-card> -->

         <div *ngIf="data">
            <button mat-button (click) = "formfour.ngSubmit.emit()" >Download</button>
         </div>
      </mat-step>
```

app.ts

```
 item1 = { isChecked: false, value: 2 };
  item2 = { isChecked: false, value: 5 };
  item3 = { isChecked: false, value: 5 };
total = 0;

updateTotal(item) {
   if(item.isChecked) {
     this.total += item.value*10;
   } else {
     this.total -= item.value*10;
   }
 }
  ngOnInit() {
 this.fourthFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      U2: [this.total]
    });
}
form4(){
    console.log(this.fourthFormGroup.value);
  }
```

in the place of "U2" updated value of "total" should be displayed. instead it displays 0 as it is defined as initial value for updating the "total" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset the formgroup value when `total` is modified.

Try like this:

```
updateTotal(item) {
   if(item.isChecked) {
     this.total += item.value*10;
   } else {
     this.total -= item.value*10;
   }
    this.fourthFormGroup.patchValue({
      U2: this.total, 
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

its showing 0 because on ngOnInit you are declaring this as 0. you need to change the value of the reactive form control using partial module update.this should be like:

```
  this.fourthFormGroup.patchValue({
   U2: this.total, 
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and explaining the solution.